# Output based on two inputs

Tags: javascript, output

I'm trying to make this "Should I take this test or that test" Calculator. Nothing is output when I put in both values, so I'm looking for the error in my code. Thanks!

```js
document.getElementById("test2score").onkeyup = function() {
  WhichTestFunction()
};

function WhichTestFunction() {
  var t1 = document.getElementById('test1score').value;
  var t2 = document.getElementById('test2score').value;

  if (t1 == 9) && (t2 < 120) {
    score = "Take Test 1";
  }

  else if (t1 == 9) && (t2 > 140) {
    score = "Take Test 2";
  }

  else if (act == 9) && (sat >= 120) && (sat <= 140) {
    score = "Toss up. Take the test you like better based on format and content.";
  }

  document.getElementById("testscore").innerHTML = score;
}
```

```html
<section id="" class="">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1">
      <h2><b>Which Test To Take?</b></h2>
      <br>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
        <h6><b>Input Test 1 Score</b></h6>
        <input type="number" id="test1score">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
        <h6><b>Input Test 2 Score</b></h6>
        <input type="number" id="test2score">
      </div>
      <p id="testscore"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: act and sat aren't defined, and score is created as a global variable which it shouldn't be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you need to wrap your `if` statements with outer parenthesis

```
if ((act == 9) && (sat >= 120) && (sat <= 140)) {...}
```

Then you have a couple of undeclared variables causing an exception

```
var score, sat, act;
```

*Note 1a: Whether these 3 variables should be declared/available globally I don't know.*

*Note 1b: As not knowing what they actually should be, I commented out that last `if` statement so the code will run in this demo sample.*

Stack snippet

```html
<section id="" class="">
    <div class="container text-center">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1">
            <h2><b>Which Test To Take?</b></h2>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
                <h6><b>Input Test 1 Score</b></h6>
                <input type="number" id="test1score">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
                <h6><b>Input Test 2 Score</b></h6>
                <input type="number" id="test2score">
            </div>
        <p id="testscore"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<script>

document.getElementById("test2score").onkeyup = function() {WhichTestFunction()};

var score, sat, act;

function WhichTestFunction() {
    var t1 = document.getElementById('test1score').value;
    var t2 = document.getElementById('test2score').value;

    if ((t1 == 9) && (t2 < 120)) {
        score = "Take Test 1";
    } 

    else if ((t1 == 9) && (t2 > 140)) {
        score = "Take Test 2";
    }
/*
    else if ((act == 9) && (sat >= 120) && (sat <= 140)) {
        score = "Toss up. Take the test you like better based on format and content.";
    }
*/
    document.getElementById("testscore").innerHTML = score;
}


</script>
```